# I rank for position 1 for 1 impression & then disappear

Tags: google-search-console

[image]

As showed in image my website rank for position 1 then disappears & I worked so hard on my website without any traffic at all can anyone help me to figure out what is going wrong

Comment: While not an exact match to your question, you should read [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) You should not assume that just because you ranked at position 1, a couple of times, that you will continue to do so.  In my experience, it's not uncommon for Google to test new URLs a couple of times in position 1 or 2, before throwing them into their normal algorithm processing.

Comment: Did it happent to you, tell me what is your website & how long it was ?